# Grant Select Privileges for a user not working?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-workbench

I am using `mysql 5.0.86` in windows machine . I am creating a user with select privileges only .

**Query**

```
Grant select on *.* to 'readonly'@'%' identified by 'readonly';
Flush privileges;
```

**MYSQL Table Output**

```
 ************************** 1. row ***************************
                Host: %
                User: readonly
            Password: *922A4B420903CAD4E7FC56A23122AB927E051FE3
         Select_priv: Y
         Insert_priv: Y
         Update_priv: Y
         Delete_priv: Y
         Create_priv: Y
           Drop_priv: Y
         Reload_priv: Y
       Shutdown_priv: Y
        Process_priv: Y
           File_priv: Y
          Grant_priv: Y
     References_priv: Y
          Index_priv: Y
          Alter_priv: Y
        Show_db_priv: Y
          Super_priv: Y
reate_tmp_table_priv: Y
    Lock_tables_priv: Y
        Execute_priv: Y
     Repl_slave_priv: Y
    Repl_client_priv: Y
    Create_view_priv: Y
      Show_view_priv: Y
 Create_routine_priv: Y
  Alter_routine_priv: Y
    Create_user_priv: Y
            ssl_type:
          ssl_cipher:
         x509_issuer:
        x509_subject:
       max_questions: 0
         max_updates: 0
     max_connections: 0
max_user_connections: 0
```

After this , I am trying to login with the created username .

```
>mysql -ureadonly -preadonly
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'readonly'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Why it's not working ?

Comment: try **>mysql -u'readonly'@'%' -preadonly**

Comment: @DhinakaranPragasam , It does not work .

Comment: @DhinakaranPragasam , In User table for the user it has entry . I already posted in my question .

+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host | User     | Password                                  |
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| %    | readonly | *922A4B420903CAD4E7FC56A23122AB927E051FE3 |
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+

Comment: @DhinakaranPragasam Yes, It works . What's the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21322/discussion-between-dhinakaran-pragasam-and-bharathi)

Answer (score 0):

Please login without password

> mysql -ureadonly

Answer (score 0):

You created user 'readonly'@'%', but connected as 'readonly'@'localhost', because  'localhost' is default host.

You need to specify **--host (-h)** option  in command line.

```
mysql -u readonly -preadonly -h <host_name>
```

Comment: `%` is an wild card character . This is for giving permission to connect from any hosts .

Comment: Specify -h option. There can be another user 'readonly'@'localhost' with another password.

Comment: I checked my mysql user table . There is no another user with this username .

Comment: Have you tried to specify -h option? It looks like MySQL tries to use 'localhost' by default, which is not a '%'.

Comment: I tried specifying localhost . But , It not works .

Thank You Devart .

Comment: Not 'localhost'. Set host name or its IP address.